Problem with installing two pods that have different version of openssl
We have 2 pods, Openpath and CGModule, each of these pods have dependencies inside of it. One of CGModule dependency is openssl.xcframework, one of Openpath dependency is OpenSSL-Universal, it has OpenSSL.xcframework, as you can see it uses the same framework, but it has different names.

When we try to install both modules using pod install command, it refuses and throw this error

target has frameworks with conflicting names: openssl.xcframework

We did try put CGModule.xcframework directly into the app project and keep Openpath install via podfile, it allows us to run pod install and build successfully, then in runtime only one openssl framework is loaded overriding another, things to know CGModule only wants import openssl and Openpath only wants import OpenSSL, it crashes at launch due to one of them doesn’t meet the expected import.
We also try put each of them to a subproject, in hope the framework targeting each subproject and doesn’t conflicted each other, but when running the build it is the same, only one openssl is loaded.
It seems that originally OpenSSL name the xcframework as openssl.xcframework, later in newer version it changed to OpenSSL.xcframework, if it has the same name it will use the newer version and both pod able to use the dependency, the different naming causing conflict.
